# Heroku Django remote: Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket? heroku django

Tags: django, heroku, web-hosting, heroku-postgres

So Ive been trying to run my django application on heroku, it works locally fine with the database, so its some issue within my base.py that I havent been yet able to identify. If anyone has encountered a similar problem and have a solution, Ive been looking around for a while no hints :(

error message:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command...
remote:
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 289, in ensure_connection
remote:     self.connect()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
remote:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 270, in connect
remote:     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
remote:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 275, in get_new_connection
remote:     connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 122, in connect
remote:     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
remote: psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server on socket   "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
remote:         Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?

base.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("APP_SECRET")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
    # Apps
    "profiles",
    "posts",
    # Django All-Auth
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
]

SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/posts"

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_UNIQUE = True


MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "social.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [BASE_DIR / "templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "profiles.context_processors.profile_pic",
                "profiles.context_processors.invitations_received_count",
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "social.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": os.environ.get("DB_NAME"),
        "USER": os.environ.get("DB_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": os.environ.get("DB_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": os.environ.get("DB_HOST"),
        "PORT": os.environ.get("DB_PORT"),
    },
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / STATIC_URL,
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static/" / "static_root"

# Media files

MEDIA_URL = "media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / MEDIA_URL

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"`
```